# Gtk3 + Glade + Python. iconview, get name selected icon

Tags: python, user-interface, gtk, glade

Good afternoon, I'm triying to get the name (HelloWord.py, for example) of the selected icon in a "iconView" file browser, but I'm not getting it.

What function should I use?

Thanks.

Comment: Probably [`get_selected_items`](http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2reference/class-gtkiconview.html#method-gtkiconview--get-selected-items) is what you need. Please add any code/snippet that you wrote so far.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I solved the problem with the "get_cursor" function, with the param "true".